# Stuck with arrays

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop, mysqli, foreach

Hi I am currently building a website where people can check the price of cyrptocurrencies. The coins I want to watch are in arrays, so it will read one by one and put it in the URL.

What I am now trying to do is to get all coins I want from the database and put it one by one in the URL. I already tried something by myself, but it is not working very well, and I am constantly getting errors or not the right result.

$array is the manual variable, and the ones above are the coins from the database

This is my code:

```
require_once('config.php');

$query = "SELECT * FROM targets";
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query);
$datas = array(); 
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $datas[] = $row;
  }
}


foreach ($datas as $data) {
  $test = "'".$data['coin']."', ";
}



$array = array('vertcoin', 'spectrecoin', 'carvertical');

foreach ($array as $coins) { 
  $url = "https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/".$coins."/";

  $ch = curl_init();

  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

  $data = curl_exec($ch);

  curl_close($ch);

  $parsed_json = json_decode($data);

  $name = $parsed_json['0']->name;
  $symbol = $parsed_json['0']->symbol;
  $price_usd = $parsed_json['0']->price_usd;
  $price_btc = $parsed_json['0']->price_btc;
  $percent_change_1h = $parsed_json['0']->percent_change_1h;
  $percent_change_24h = $parsed_json['0']->percent_change_24h;
  $percent_change_7d = $parsed_json['0']->percent_change_7d;

  echo "<br><br>name: ". $name ."<br>";
  echo "symbol: ". $symbol ."<br>";
  echo "price_usd: ". $price_usd ."<br>";
  echo "price_btc: ". $price_btc ."<br>";
  echo "1h change: ". $percent_change_1h ."<br>";
  echo "24h change: ". $percent_change_24h ."<br>";
  echo "7d change: ". $percent_change_7d ."<br><br>";

}
```

Comment: The line if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) is useless. The while loop will not execute if there isnt any value in $result

Comment: Thanks for posting your code. Please also post your table definition and show what error you are getting.

Comment: "*but it is not working very well, and I am constantly getting errors or not the right result*" ... please elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are overwritting the `$test` value each time.

I do not understant which variable is what, but If I am not wrong the following statement is where you try to concatenate your values:

```
foreach ($datas as $data) {
  if($test){
      //when $test is not null remember the value.
      $test = $test."'".$data['coin']."', ";
  }else{
      //Otherwise set $test
      $test = "'".$data['coin']."', ";
  }
}
```

Comment: He doesn't even use $test anywhere. I believe thats leftover code from trying to debug something.

Comment: Yes, I don't know exactly the meaning of each variable, so I tried to help a little blind about what is each thing.

Comment: The whole question is unclear lol. Props for trying... but it may be a fruitless endeavor ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE `targets` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `coin` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

With this data:

```
INSERT INTO `targets` (`id`, `coin`) VALUES
(1, 'vertcoin'),
(2, 'spectrecoin'),
(3, 'carvertical');
```

This code:

```
require_once 'config.php';

$query = "SELECT * FROM targets";
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query);
$coinList = array(); 
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $coinList[] = $row['coin'];
    }
}

//print_r($datas);
foreach ($coinList as $coinItem) { 
    $url = "https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/".$coinItem."/";
    echo sprintf('URL for coin '%s' is %s', $coinItem, $url);
    // Rest of code goes here.
    // curl etc.
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    $parsed_json = json_decode($data);
    $name = $parsed_json['0']->name;
    $symbol = $parsed_json['0']->symbol;
    $price_usd = $parsed_json['0']->price_usd;
    $price_btc = $parsed_json['0']->price_btc;
    $percent_change_1h = $parsed_json['0']->percent_change_1h;
    $percent_change_24h = $parsed_json['0']->percent_change_24h;
    $percent_change_7d = $parsed_json['0']->percent_change_7d;

    echo "<br><br>name: ". $name ."<br>";
    echo "symbol: ". $symbol ."<br>";
    echo "price_usd: ". $price_usd ."<br>";
    echo "price_btc: ". $price_btc ."<br>";
    echo "1h change: ". $percent_change_1h ."<br>";
    echo "24h change: ". $percent_change_24h ."<br>";
    echo "7d change: ". $percent_change_7d ."<br><br>";
}
```

Produces this output:

```
URL for coin vertcoin is https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/vertcoin/


name: Vertcoin
symbol: VTC
price_usd: 4.53398
price_btc: 0.00040362
1h change: -0.11
24h change: -2.77
7d change: 6.88

URL for coin spectrecoin is https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/spectrecoin/


name: Spectrecoin
symbol: XSPEC
price_usd: 2.93546
price_btc: 0.00026103
1h change: 0.01
24h change: -3.42
7d change: 14.64

URL for coin carvertical is https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/carvertical/


name: carVertical
symbol: CV
price_usd: 0.011548
price_btc: 0.00000103
1h change: 3.75
24h change: -8.44
7d change:
```